# Why MSE from Keras is not the same as what I calculate?

Tags: keras, neural-network

I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K

a=1

def my_regularizer(inputs):
    means=K.mean((inputs),axis=1)
    return a*K.sum(means)**2

x_train=np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(200,2))
x_test=np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(20,2))
model=Sequential([
     Dense(20,input_shape=(2,),activity_regularizer=my_regularizer),
     Activation('tanh'),
     Dense(2,),
     Activation('linear')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
hist=model.fit(x_train,x_train,epochs=10,verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test,x_test))

print('MSE from Keras: ',hist.history['val_loss'][-1])
y_pred=model.predict(x_test)
print('Calculated MSE: ', np.mean((y_pred-x_test)**2))
```

The output is:

```
MSE from Keras:  0.1555381715297699
Calculated MSE:  0.12031101597786406
```

If I remove `activity_regularizer=my_regularizer`, then they will be closer, but still different:

```
MSE from Keras:  0.09773887693881989
Calculated MSE:  0.09773887699599623
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870408/why-mse-calculated-by-keras-compile-is-different-from-mse-calculated-by-scikit-l   but the author did not provide and example. Your example is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is clear. You have a regularizer. 
The role of the regularizer is to add a term to the loss function, so it's the expected behavior to have a greater loss.

For the other little difference, it's just precision. Maybe using float 32 vs float 64, or doing calculations on the GPU x CPU with different algorythms. I would not worry about that difference.